# convert rdl to rdlc?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am using visual studio 2008 and reporting service 2008.

I created a `.rdl` reports. Now I want to convert `.rdl` to `.rdlc`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. According to spec whey should be more or less the same, but in reality they differ wildly depending on version. For instance if I open an RDLC file I created in Visual Studio 2010 in Report Builder 3.0 it works. But if I make a change in my RDL(C) file and try to open it in VS2010 I first get asked if I want to convert it to RDLC 2008 format (yes) and then I get the error message "The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded."

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to convert. All you have to do is to rename the file to .rdlc. This converts it from a server report to a client report. The underlying schema is the same, whether it's an .rdl or .rdlc file.

Take a look at FAQ #8 here: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

Comment: There is a bit more involved than just changing the file extension.

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs - This wasn't the case 6+ years ago when the question was asked.

Comment: My apologies... I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days now... and I am coming to the conclusion that much of what is written and documented about conversion is older and no longer applies. Even following MSDN's own documentation in how to do this is not getting the trick done anymore! It seems to me that you should just be able to "Save As" .rdlc when you want to but neither VS or Report Builder give that option :(

Answer (score 1):

I found working with MS support that converting an RDL to RDLC merely by changing the extensions results in a ReportViewer Control HTTPHandler error which is shown with a style of "dsiplay:none".  It accuses the developer of not including the HTTPHandler in the web.config, when it is actually in the web.config.  Using an rdlc created by VS in that project, then the reportviewer opens just fine and properly displays.  MS support and I are still researching what other changes need to be made, but as of now, I can let people know not to drink the MSDN Kool-Aid.

I also tried changing the schemas namespace in the XML file and I got the same report definition cited above.